# python executing grep with subprocess not working

Tags: python, shell, grep

Trying to `subprocess` out to do a recursive grep.  Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, check_output

try:
    out = check_output(
        ["grep",
         "-R",
         '--include="*.org"',
         "abc",
         "/home/fenton/projects/docs-DIR/documentation/"],
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(out)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print("command failed")
```

When I run it, it fails.

```
python % python find_docs_2.py
command failed
```

Doing this from the command line succeeds:

```
python % grep -R --include="*.org" abc /home/fenton/projects/docs-DIR/documentation/
/home/fenton/projects/docs-DIR/documentation/zsh.org:    % ./test.sh -f abc
/home/fenton/projects/docs-DIR/documentation/zsh.org:    abc
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
```

and it will print the problem

Comment: tried that already. no helpful error message.  maybe should have left that in the code to demonstrate that. it, just does: `python % python find_docs_2.py 
command failed
b''`

Comment: What I did was run it from the interactive prompt and saved the `e` to a global value.  Then I could analyze the exception in detail.